# Laravel - Error target class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer, laravel-6

Tengo un proyecto en laravel que es una API y un pequeño frontal con blade, en local me funciona todo correctamente, pero cuando hago deploy al servidor me ocurre lo siguiente.

La arquitectura del proyecto es esta , como podeis observar es la estructura "standard" de un proyecto laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues tengo un formulario que hace una acción y al hacer el post me da este error.
Como podeis observar hace referencia a **API** cuando yo tengo ese directorio en minusculas como **Api** .

He probado a hacer un composer dump-autoload , limpiar todas las cache de laravel con los comandos siguientes, pero **no consigo** hacerlo funcionar.

```
# Clear and cache routes
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache

# Clear and cache config
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hago un "php artisan route list" la salida por consola es esta

```
user1@machine:/var/www/html/test_web$ php artisan route:list


In Container.php line 805:

  Target class [App\Http\Controllers\API\TallerController] does not exist.


In Container.php line 803:

  Class App\Http\Controllers\API\TallerController does not exist
```

Pero si voy a la carpeta, el fichero está

```
user1@machine:/var/www/html/test_web/app/Http/Controllers/Api$ ls -alh TallerController.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 4.9K Feb  6 16:27 TallerController.php
```

Comment: Usualmente puedes encontrar más información del error en el logger de laravel, revisa si tienes más información adicional para que la compartas, tambien puedes hacer uso del comando `php artisan route:list` puede que tu controlador tenga algun problema

Comment: Gracias eso fué lo primero que miré. Adjunto unas capturas en el 1º post sobre las rutas.

Comment: Eso tiene que ver con en `namespace`, no con directorio. Posiblemente lo tengas mal declarado en las rutas o el controlador

Comment: Agrega el controlador, puede ser el problema que menciona @porloscerrosΨ o puede ser incluso el problema en el middleware de la api

Comment: Lo acabo de encontrar...el problema es que desarrollo en windows y no es case-sensitive...pero hago deploy en linux...donde si lo es...y resulta que en el fichero de rutas lo tenia como "API\..." por eso en windows me funcionava...en linux no.

Comment: Talvez se la versión de laravel.
ve el siguiente video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQ55nqUGBK8